# Conditional statement in CFSet

Tags: coldfusion, conditional-statements, coldfusion-8

I can't remember what it is called, but I need to do a sort of conditional statement inside of a CFSet statement.  What I mean is something like the following

```
siteSettings = {
    mailserversmtpport = resourceBean.getValue('mailsmtp'), // SMTP Port (If the method returns no len() then default to 25)
    mailserverpopport = resourceBean.getValue('mailpop'), // POP port (If the method returns no len() then default to 110)
};
```

So I am building a structure with the smtp and pop port for a mail server.  I have a method call that gets a value from a bean.  If that value doesn't exist then it is just going to return a 0 length string.  Is it possible (in ColdFusion 8) to have the value be 25 and 110 if returned values have no length without do cfif statements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The neatest, and in my opinion best, way to do this would be to add two methods to your bean: getMailSmtp() and getMailPop().

Put the conditional logic in there - so the method returns your default value if it's not specified.

Something like this:

```
<cffunction name="getMailSmtp" returntype="string" output="false">
    <cfif len(getValue("mailsmtp"))>
        <cfreturn getValue("mailsmtp") />
    <cfelse>
        <cfreturn 25 />
    </cfif>
</cffunction>
```

Alternatively, you could alter your getValue() method to accept a second argument - a default value. Then, if the value doesn't exist, it would return the default:

```
resourceBean.getValue("mailsmtp", 25)
```

I'd personally go for the first method, as this means that any time you call getMailSmtp() in your application, the logic is applied.

You could even combine the methods, so your getMailSmtp() method returns `getValue("mailsmtp", 25)`.

Comment: Good thinking, Seb. Generally speaking, the "smarter" you can make your beans the better.

Answer (score 3):

```
siteSettings = {
mailserversmtpport = iif(len(resourceBean.getValue('mailsmtp')),de(resourceBean.getValue('mailsmtp')),de(25)),
mailserverpopport = iif(len(resourceBean.getValue('mailpop')),de(resourceBean.getValue('mailpop')),de(110))
};
```

Comment: As the values involved are numbers you don't need to use the delayed evaluation, De(), function. Less typing and probably a little faster.

Comment: I try to avoid using IIF whenever possible, but this is the correct way to do what you're asking. It is much more preferable to use IF/ELSE statements, rather than IIF inside a CFSET.

Comment: @CfSimplicity, force of habit on my part. You are absolutely correct.

Answer (score 0):

Not a big fan of iif. Your probably thinking of the ternary operator.

which is

```
<cfset x > 3 ? true : false />
```

But it's CF9 only

Comment: Me neither. Unfortunately they are using CF8 though.

Comment: I new about iif, but I was looking for the ternary operator.  I like sebduggan's answer the best though as it is clean.